# Contract could not be found in the list of contracts

Tags: c#, wcf, service, contract

I've got a project that i need to test, it's a service built around a contract(wcf i think??). I get the following error msg when i try to start it:

```
Error starting service: The contract name 'VMBRLight.VMBRService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'VMBRLight.VMBRService'.
```

Where can i find the list of contracts implemented??

This is code that i think is relevant, implementation of service:

```
namespace VMBRLight
{
    [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "", Name = "VMBRLight.VMBRService", InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
        ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = false, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = false,
        MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647, TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)]
    public class VMBRLightService : VMBRService
    {
```

Config

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="VMBRLightServiceBehavior" name="VMBRLight.VMBRLightService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5250/VMBRLightService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="VMBRLight.VMBRService" bindingConfiguration="WebBinding" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
```

Comment: Can you show what `VMBRLight.VMBRService` looks like?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the [Service Contract] attribute in the above code for the class VMBRLightService

```
namespace VMBRLight
{
    [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "", Name = "VMBRLight.VMBRService", InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
        ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = false, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = false,
        MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647, TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)]
   ***[ServiceContract]***
    public class VMBRLightService : VMBRService
    {
```